# How to retry the generator

Tags: python, decorator

When an exception occurs, how to retry code 2 code without changing code 2?

Tried the decorator again, but the session_scope is generator

thank you very much

code 1

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope(commit=True):
    session = sessionmaker()
    try:
        yield session
        if commit:
            session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

code 2:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    session.add(xxx)
    session.add(yyy)
    # raise Exception eg: 1/0
    a = 1/0
    session.add(zzz)
```

Supplementary note: Any line of code in code 2 may fail to run and the entire block of code must be retryed. I want to retry code 2 without changing the code of code 2, such as retrying at most three times, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you want to do?  What does "retry code 2 code" mean?  You want to execute `session.add(xxx)` and `session.add(yyy)` again after handling the exception?  You want to do this while only being able to change the `session_scope` function?  I don't see how you can expect that there's any way to do that.  When the divide by zero error occurs, the first two `add` calls have already been made, and there's no way to go back and rerun those lines.  If you could run them again, then wouldn't you end up in an infinite loop, failing over and over?

Comment: In code2, the use of session may cause the session to be unavailable due to abnormal network jitter, so the entire block of code must be retried. For example, a maximum of 3 retries will not cause an endless loop. I want to know if there is a good way to retry code 2 without changing code 2。thanks

Comment: Nothing you show provides a way to run "code 2" a second time.  So pretty much by definition, there's no visible way to run it again.  But there are a number of ways that you could cause it to be retryable.  You could put the "code 2" code in a function or an anonymous function (lambda) and then pass a reference to the code into another function that is responsible for retrying on failure.  Since that code then has a pointer to the "code 2" code, it could call it multiple times if necessary.